# Example to add debounce to autocomplete Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, lodash, antd, debouncing

I need a bit of help here, I am new to react and I have this doubt.

I am not getting a working example of a to AutoComplete with `debounce`. i.e. my AutoComplete component is delaying in displaying entered text and while I am searching the solution for this I got to know we can overcome this by using AutoComplete with debounce. So please anyone can help with this by adding debounce to given sandbox link OR can suggest to me why it is delaying while displaying the entered text. Thank you.

Reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-galois-5v1mi

Comment: I cannot see a delay in the code sandbox. Btw, debounce actually serves to create a delay, so I don't really understand, because this  `please anyone can help with this by adding debounce`  contradicts with this `can suggest to me why it is delaying`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use debounce method from lodash.

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

<AutoComplete
  ...,
  onSearch={debounce(handleSearch, 300)} // 300 is your required delay
/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding debounce inline will often result in triggering on each keystroke.
If you want to debounce after the user has finished their key strokes then you will need to use `useCallback`.

Example -

```
const debouncedSearch = useCallback(
    debounce(nextValue => onSearch(nextValue), 1000),
    [], // will be created only once initially
);

const handleSearch = event => {
    event.persist();
    const { value: nextValue } = event.target;
    // Even though handleSearch is created on each render and executed
    // it references the same debouncedSearch that was created initially
    debouncedSearch(nextValue);
};

<AutoComplete
  ...,
  onSearch={handleSearch}
/>
```

I found this article useful and a recommended read.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/debounce-and-throttle-in-react-with-hooks/

Answer (score 1):

I tried the existing answers for this question (given by [Fatemeh Qasemkhani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7093797/fatemeh-qasemkhani) and [justuff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1825010/justuff)), but it didn't work for some reason.

Had to do a bit more research and found the below article : [How to Correctly Debounce and Throttle Callbacks in React](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-throttle-debounce/)

---

Below code is similar to the code I used to implement this feature :

```
import { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

function MyComponent() {
  const handleSearch = () => {
    // handle the search event...
  };

  const debouncedChangeHandler = useMemo(
    () => debounce(handleSearch , 300), []
   );
     
  // Stop the invocation of the debounced function
  // after unmounting
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      debouncedChangeHandler.cancel();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
     <AutoComplete
       ...,
       onSearch={debouncedChangeHandler}
      />         
    </div>
   );
  }
```